# Reflexivity, Transitivity, Symmertry of the square of an relation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

$\def\p{\mathrel p}$If $\p$ is a relation on a set $A$, define $\p^2$ by $a \mathrel{\p^2} b$ if and only if there exists $c$ with $a \p c$ and $c \p b$.

If $p$ is reflexive/symmetric/transitive does $p^2$ have the same properties?

I'm not even sure how to start this, I assume I would need to use the $a$ related to $c$, $c$ related to $b$ somehow?

Comment: In the FAQ section you'll find directions on how to use LaTeX to properly write mathematics in this site. In your this is even more urgent as you use lots of letter in the middle and one can hardly tell them apart.

Comment: Proceed by attempting to connect the definition of $p$ being reflexive / symmetric / transitive to the definition of $p^2$ being the same property. For example, if $a~p~a$ for all $a$ (i.e. $p$ is reflexive), then for each $a$, there exists a $c$ such that $a~p~c$ and $c~p~a$ (namely $c=a$), hence $p^2$ is reflexive. And so on.

Answer (score 1):

Let's do reflexivity: Suppose, $p$ is reflexive. Let $a \in A$. We want to show that $a \mathrel{p^2} a$. By the definition of $p^2$, we have to find a $c \in A$ with $a \mathrel p c$, $c \mathrel p a$. But by the reflexivity of $p$, we know that $a \mathrel p a$. So if we let $c = a$, we have $a \mathrel p c$, $c \mathrel p a$, so $a \mathrel{p^2} a$ holds and $p$ is reflexive.

I hope, this will help you to do symmetry and transitivity on your own.

Comment: how would I do the transitivity... this is what ive got. We know that p is transitive so a p b, b p c, a p c. So since a p c we know that c = a, and then b = a and everything is equal so its all transitive? and the a $p^2$ b and b $p^2$ c so therefor a $p^2$ c

Comment: No. First recal want you want to prove, namely that $a \mathrel{p^2} b$, $b \mathrel{p^2} c$ implies $a \mathrel{p^2} c$. Now write down the defintion of $p^2$ ...

Comment: Okay So I know a **$p^2$** b if and only if a **p** c and c **p** b. Right so i  know that since i supposed p is transitive that a **p** c. so bam, i get a **p** c from the transitivity of **p**. so then a **$p^2$** b and if we say b **$p^2$** c then we know that since a =  b, that b = c?